# Getting strange exception while deleting sms from inbox

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, sms

I am writing a project to delete sms from inbox.Most of the times it works fine,but sometime it gives strange exception.This is the stacktrace of exception:

```
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: error code 14: unable to open database file
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:503)
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:723)
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at com.velosys.smsManager.Database.DatabaseHandlerRule.DeleteMessagesFromInbox(DatabaseHandlerRule.java:1441)
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at com.velosys.smsManager.Database.DatabaseHandlerRule.deleteContactOnBasisOfTime(DatabaseHandlerRule.java:1375)
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at com.velosys.smsManager.Activities.SplashActivity$2.run(SplashActivity.java:132)
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:618)
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:123)
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3850)
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
01-23 16:41:20.016: E/AndroidRuntime(7328):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the line where i am deleting the sms from inbox and getting the exception:

```
l_contentResolver.delete(deleteUri, "address = ?" +" AND "+"date = ?",
                    new String[] {PhoneNumber,String.valueOf(DateandTime)});
```

This is the deleteUri:

```
Uri deleteUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
```

This is l_contentResolver:

```
ContentResolver l_contentResolver = activity.getContentResolver();
```

I searched a lot about this exception but am not to figure out the reason for this in my code.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is a problem in your code. If it only occurs in very few cases it is an error in the ContentProvider that manages the SMS.

Since the SMS API is not a public part of the Android API i don't think that there is some kind of documentation about this problems or a place to flag this as an Android Bug.

Maybe retry to delete the message a little bit later.